# How to remove the leading zero from number using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I use this pattern to check for numbers only in a quantity field from 0 to whatever. how can I make the code not allow 012, 010.. etc I mean the starting zero, but still allow 0 as standalone number.

0, 1, 10, 1, etc. are ok,

but not allow 012, 005, etc.

Is there a pattern that does that?

Here is my code but the problem with it, it removes the 0, even if it is not leading in number which I want to avoid. I want to allow the 0 as standalone number in my field.

```
$('.td-qnt input').live('change keyup blur', function(e) {
    var re = /^[0-9]\d*$/;
    var str = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(str.replace(/^[ 0]/g,''));
    if (re.test(str)){
        var price = $(this).parent().parent().prev('td').html();
        var realprice = price.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');  
        var result = realprice * str;
        var subtotal = result.toFixed(2);
        $(this).parent().parent().next('td').html('$'+subtotal);
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().next('td').html('$0.00');
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need jquery to do that?

Comment: Updating cart total/subtotal (client side) before sending it server side and validating it again. Just for visual / client side perfection.

Comment: try `parseInt(str);`. don't see a need for all this pregging.

Comment: or `parseFloat(str);` in the case of a floaty price type number.

Comment: @AhmedFouad, it's totally overkill to use jquery is what I was meaning. Javascript will solve this alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"" + parseFloat(str)
```

Works out what the numerica value is, then makes it a string again. Bingo, no leading zeros.

Comment: or `parseInt` if str is an int.

Comment: @yitwail `str` clearly isn't an int; it's a string! But yes, `parseInt` if you want to treat it as an integer, `parseFloat` if you want to include any decimal part it might have.

Comment: I should have said `str` contains only numeric characters I suppose. I got a bit lazy. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement, but in my situation, I clean input on key up.  parseInt and parseFloat both clear leading zeros, but parseFloat also clears the decimal if there aren't trailing numbers.  So I wrote this:

```
function removeLeadingZeros(target){
    var finished=false;
    var localTarget=target;
    var firstDigit;
    var secondDigit;
    while (!finished){
        firstDigit=localTarget.substring(0,1);
        secondDigit=localTarget.substring(1,2);
        if (firstDigit == '0' && !(secondDigit == '.' || secondDigit == ''))
            localTarget=localTarget.substring(1);
        else
            finished=true;
    }
    return localTarget;
}
```

This handles user input directly into a field or a paste like "0003".